# Technique for finding bad data in read.csv in R

Tags: r

I am reading in a file of data that looks like this:

```
userId, fullName,email,password,activated,registrationDate,locale,notifyOnUpdates,lastSyncTime,plan_id,plan_period_months,plan_price,plan_exp_date,plan_is_trial,plan_is_trial_used,q_hear,q_occupation,pp_subid,pp_payments,pp_since,pp_cancelled,apikey
"2","John Smith,"john.smith@gmail.com","a","1","2004-07-23 14:19:32","en_US","1","2011-04-07 07:29:17","3",\N,\N,\N,"0","1",\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,"d7734dce-4ae2-102a-8951-0040ca38ff83"
```

but the actual file as around 20000 records. I use the following R code to read it in:

```
user = read.csv("~/Desktop/dbdump/users.txt", na.strings = "\\N", quote="")
```

And the reason I have `quote=""` is because without it the import stops prematurely. I end up with a total of 9569 observations. Why I don't understand why exactly the `quote=""` overcomes this problem, it *seems* to do so.

Except that it introduces other problems that I have to 'fix'. The first one I saw is that the dates end up being strings which include the quotes, which don't want to convert to actual dates when I use `to.Date()` on them.

Now I could fix the strings and hack my way through. But better to know more about what I am doing. Can someone explain:

1. Why does the `quote=""` fix the 'bad data'
2. What is a best-practice technique to figure out what is causing the `read.csv` to stop early? (If I just look at the input data at +/- the indicated row, I don't see anything amiss).

Here are the lines 'near' the 'problem'. I don't see the damage do you?

```
"16888","user1","user1@gmail.com","TeilS12","1","2008-01-19 08:47:45","en_US","0","2008-02-23 16:51:53","1",\N,\N,\N,"0","0","article","student",\N,\N,\N,\N,"ad949a8e-17ed-102b-9237-0040ca390025"
"16889","user2","user2@gmail.com","Gaspar","1","2008-01-19 10:34:11","en_US","1",\N,"1",\N,\N,\N,"0","0","email","journalist",\N,\N,\N,\N,"8b90f63a-17fc-102b-9237-0040ca390025"
"16890","user3","user3@gmail.com","boomblaadje","1","2008-01-19 14:36:54","en_US","0",\N,"1",\N,\N,\N,"0","0","article","student",\N,\N,\N,\N,"73f31f4a-181e-102b-9237-0040ca390025"
"16891","user4","user4@gmail.com","mytyty","1","2008-01-19 15:10:45","en_US","1","2008-01-19 15:16:45","1",\N,\N,\N,"0","0","google-ad","student",\N,\N,\N,\N,"2e48e308-1823-102b-9237-0040ca390025"
"16892","user5","user5@gmail.com","08091969","1","2008-01-19 15:12:50","en_US","1",\N,"1",\N,\N,\N,"0","0","dont","dont",\N,\N,\N,\N,"79051bc8-1823-102b-9237-0040ca390025"
```

*** Update ***

It's more tricky. Even though the total number of rows imported is 9569, if I look at the last few rows they correspond to the last few rows of data. Therefore I surmise that something happened during the import to cause a lot of rows to be skipped. In fact 15914 - 9569 = 6345 records. When I have the quote="" in there I get 15914.

So my question can be modified: Is there a way to get read.csv to report about rows it decides not to import?

*** UPDATE 2 ***

@Dwin, I had to remove na.strings="\N" because the count.fields function doesn't permit it. With that, I get this output which looks interesting but I don't understand it.

```
3     4    22    23    24 
1    83 15466   178     4
```

Your second command produces a lots of data (and stops when max.print is reached.) But the first row is this:

```
[1]  2  4  2  3  5  3  3  3  5  3  3  3  2  3  4  2  3  2  2  3  2  2  4  2  4  3  5  4  3  4  3  3  3  3  3  2  4
```

Which I don't understand if the output is supposed to show how many fields there are in each record of input. Clearly the first lines all have more than 2,4,2 etc fields... Feel like I am getting closer, but still confused!

Comment: Can you show us what the data looks like before `quote = ""` and after? Or, can you post a few more lines of your data, preferably some "healthy" ones and some bad ones? In short, can you make a reproducible example?

Comment: I vote for embedded commas!

Comment: @roman: the problem is that I don't know where the bad data is. I can show you the lines +/- 9569 and maybe you will see what I am missing.

Comment: The problem pretty much has to be either in the last row you are able to read or the first one you aren't (assuming it's not a matter of skipped rows in the middle somewhere). Show us those two rows as they look in the source file. -- or collect them with `readLines` .

Comment: BTW, if I do `as.Date("2004-07-23 14:19:32")` I get a date-type variable just fine.

Comment: @carl: my case is this: as.Date('\"2004-07-23 14:19:32\"')
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: @carl: See my *update* above: it seems to be rows in the middle that are skipped.

Comment: My usual workaround (typical for Excel-exported file): force all columns to be read as string, and handle problem in R.

Comment: What does this show: `table( count.fields("~/Desktop/dbdump/users.txt", na.strings = "\\N", quote="", sep=",") )` ... and also this: `table( count.fields("~/Desktop/dbdump/users.txt", na.strings = "\\N", quote="", comment.char="") )`

Comment: @DWin: I added answers to the main question above (to preserve format)

Comment: Within the read.csv command you can use the options skip=n and nrows=m to start the read at line n and read the next m rows.  Using this you should be able to identify exactly some problem rows. Try this with and without quote="".    By the way the quote option specifies what is used to delimit character strings.   I think you need to try quote="\"" vice quote="".

Comment: You can get a list of the line positions with non-22 values (using the comma and non-quote settings): `which( count.fields("~/Desktop/dbdump/users.txt", quote="", sep=",") != 22)`

Comment: @DWin: you got it! I found the lines. Very good! Thanks, I learned a lot. And to others, thanks! Indeed I found some commas inside text string and even a pound sign ! Thanks!

Comment: I find it very strange that your output "randomly" misses an end quote on a field. Where are these data coming from?

Comment: @brandon: that was just my own typo. I was manually scrubbing real emails from my data and made a typo, that's all.

Comment: Doggone it- someone recently posted a detailed workaround using `readLines` and some parsing-fu, but I can't track down the link.

Comment: If these data originate from a database, it's likely that there is an R package that can interface with the database directly - avoiding this problem entirely. This is why I asked where these data are coming from.

Answer (score 4):

One problem I have spotted (thanks to `data.table`) is the missing quote (") after `John Smith`. Could this be a problem also for other lines you have?

If I add the "missing" quote after `John Smith`, it reads fine.

I saved this data to `data.txt`:

```
userId, fullName,email,password,activated,registrationDate,locale,notifyOnUpdates,lastSyncTime,plan_id,plan_period_months,plan_price,plan_exp_date,plan_is_trial,plan_is_trial_used,q_hear,q_occupation,pp_subid,pp_payments,pp_since,pp_cancelled,apikey
"2","John Smith","john.smith@gmail.com","a","1","2004-07-23 14:19:32","en_US","1","2011-04-07 07:29:17","3",\N,\N,\N,"0","1",\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,"d7734dce-4ae2-102a-8951-0040ca38ff83"
"16888","user1","user1@gmail.com","TeilS12","1","2008-01-19 08:47:45","en_US","0","2008-02-23 16:51:53","1",\N,\N,\N,"0","0","article","student",\N,\N,\N,\N,"ad949a8e-17ed-102b-9237-0040ca390025"
"16889","user2","user2@gmail.com","Gaspar","1","2008-01-19 10:34:11","en_US","1",\N,"1",\N,\N,\N,"0","0","email","journalist",\N,\N,\N,\N,"8b90f63a-17fc-102b-9237-0040ca390025"
"16890","user3","user3@gmail.com","boomblaadje","1","2008-01-19 14:36:54","en_US","0",\N,"1",\N,\N,\N,"0","0","article","student",\N,\N,\N,\N,"73f31f4a-181e-102b-9237-0040ca390025"
"16891","user4","user4@gmail.com","mytyty","1","2008-01-19 15:10:45","en_US","1","2008-01-19 15:16:45","1",\N,\N,\N,"0","0","google-ad","student",\N,\N,\N,\N,"2e48e308-1823-102b-9237-0040ca390025"
"16892","user5","user5@gmail.com","08091969","1","2008-01-19 15:12:50","en_US","1",\N,"1",\N,\N,\N,"0","0","dont","dont",\N,\N,\N,\N,"79051bc8-1823-102b-9237-0040ca390025"
```

And this is a code. Both `fread` and `read.csv` works fine.

```
require(data.table)

dat1 <- fread("data.txt", header = T, na.strings = "\\N")
dat1

dat2 <- read.csv("data.txt", header = T, na.strings = "\\N")
dat2
```

Answer (score 4):

The `count.fields` function can be very useful in identifying where to look for malformed data.

This gives a tabulation of fields per line ignores quoting, possibly a problem if there are embedded commas:

```
table( count.fields("~/Desktop/dbdump/users.txt", quote="", sep=",") )
```

This give a tabulation ignoring both quotes and "#"(octothorpe) as a comment character:

```
table( count.fields("~/Desktop/dbdump/users.txt",  quote="", comment.char="") )
```

Atfer seeing what you report for the first tabulation..... most of which were as desired ... You can get a list of the line positions with non-22 values (using the comma and non-quote settings):

```
which( count.fields("~/Desktop/dbdump/users.txt", quote="", sep=",") != 22)
```

Sometimes the problem can be solved with `fill=TRUE` if the only difficulty is missing commas at the ends of lines.

Comment: This is a much better version of my suggestion. +1