# How to avoid EOF within quoted string?

Tags: r, read.table

I have a large txt (400MB) file and the columns are separated by `###` instead of `,` or `;`.

Among the thing I have tried this is one of them

```
raw2 <- readLines("myfile.txt")

raw2 <- gsub("###", "|", raw2)

raw3 <- read.table("raw2.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "|")
```

but I keep obtaining:

```
Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string
```

Is there some recommended efficient way to read a long table?

Even when this seems to be a duplicate of [Technique for finding bad data in read.csv in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771557/technique-for-finding-bad-data-in-read-csv-in-r) my situation is that I cannot do the most *logical* thing that would be to use `sep = "###"`as that returns this error

```
invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte
```

Comment: Why can't you `read.table("myfile.txt", sep = "###")`?

Comment: because that is "illegal" and it says `invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte`